# Returning a mock response in a service worker when a POST request is made whilst the application is offline

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, blazor-webassembly

I am updating a service worker in a Blazor WASM PWA application in an attempt to defer POST requests if they are made whilst the application is offline.

If the application is online, it will perform the request over the network and it works fine. When the application is offline, I intend to save the POST request to IndexedDb and execute it when the application is online.

I am trying to return a response so the application thinks that the POST request has been performed correctly and can continue to execute.

```
async function onFetch(event) {
    const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
    let cachedResponse = null;

    if (event.request.method === 'GET') {

        const shouldServeIndexHtml = event.request.mode === 'navigate';
        const request = shouldServeIndexHtml ? 'index.html' : event.request;
        cachedResponse = await cache.match(request);

        if (cachedResponse == undefined) {
            const fetchResponse = await fetch(event.request.url);
            cache.put(event.request.url, fetchResponse.clone());
            return fetchResponse;
        }

        return cachedResponse;
    }
    else if (event.request.method === 'POST') {

        var reqUrl = event.request.url;
        var authHeader = event.request.headers.get('Authorization');

        // get the request body
        Promise.resolve(event.request.text()).then((payload) => {

            // if online, perform request as normal
            if (navigator.onLine) {
                return fetch(reqUrl, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: payload
                });
            } else {
                // if offline, save request to IndexedDb
                // saveIntoIndexedDb(reqUrl, authHeader, payload);

                // attempt to return mock response so application can continue to execute
                const myOptions = { status: 200, statusText: "Fabulous" };
                return new Response(payload, myOptions);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Error is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Maybe try to return the `Promise.resolve`? Not sure how exactly onFetch works, so I don't know if it's a solution. But if you don't return the promise, then returning within the callbacks (eg the last `return new Response`) will go nowhere and has no effect

Comment: That's done it!!! Thank you. Is it obvious I don't often write JavaScript lol. So if I weren't returning it, would awaiting it also work?

Comment: You could also use `const res = await event.request.text().then(...); return res`. The main point is, that you return it, such that the caller of `onFetch` can use it afterwards